# boost program options count number of occurrences of a flag

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am trying to program in a way for the user of my program to specify the level of verbosity of my program from 0 to 3. I was told by someone that there might be a way to set up the program options so that I am able to detect the number of occurrences of a flag, and then run my program accordingly.

Example:
`[none] -> level 0`
`-v -> level 1`
`-vv -> level 2`
`-vvv -> level 3`

Does anyone know if this is possible? Do I just need to set up three different options, one for each possibility? I have tried to search around for a similar example however I fear I may be searching the wrong things.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a nice way. `boost::program_options` option syntax is a little more structured (and arguably more simplistic) than `getopt`.

Here's one way:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    std::string verbosity_values;

    po::options_description desc("Command Line Options");
    desc.add_options()("verbosity,v",
                       po::value(&verbosity_values)->implicit_value(""),
                       "verbose");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("verbosity")) {
        verbosity_values += "v";
    }

    if (std::any_of(begin(verbosity_values), end(verbosity_values), [](auto&c) { return c != 'v'; })) {
        std::cerr << "invalid verbosity" << std::endl;
        std::exit(100);
    }

    std::cout << "verbosity: " << verbosity_values.size() << std::endl;

}
```

How it works:

1. define an option called "--verbosity" with a synonym "-v".
2. 'verbosity' takes a string argument, which we default to ""
3. we check that the string contains only 'v's
4. if the `variables_map` contains a 'verbosity' argument, then -v or --verbosity must have been mentioned on the command line. Therefore, add a 'v' to the string.
5. verbosity is the length of the string.

example:

```
$ ./a.out -vvvv
verbosity: 4
$
```

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean about that not being very clean, however it does what I want it to. My concern now is that it does not place nice with other option (for example, `-vvdb` would give me "Invalid verbosity", even if I had other flags with synonyms `d` and `b`. However, I assume this is unavoidable and I can just indicate in the docs that the verbosity needs to be specified separately.

Comment: Also - I am now running into the problem where I am unable to pass in a positional argument (input file) if the `-v` option is one before. It works if there is more than one v (ex: `-vv input_file` or if I include another argument after a single v `-v -d input_file`, but not otherwise (`-v input_file`)  Any clue?